# What is the best way to use IE webBrowser control without requiring MS/Visual studio run times?

Tags: c++, html, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, exe

What I am trying to do is create an exe (not .hta) that can be programmed to open a local html file and have it work just like it was in IE (handle styles, scripts and etc), only without actually loading IE. The exe must also be run without installation requirements, and no dependencies (other than recent IE obviously), needed on the host machine.

The purpose is to create an interactive e-book type document, that can be edited without recompile, and also be run from cd/usb on the fly.

I can't just open IE, because it will look unprofessional with the big E, the toolbar and tabs all at the top. know what I mean?

I have experience with HTA, and this was my first suggestion, however I would like to take advantage of the auto run from cd, and also to make the form border a little different, less plain.

I also have experience in VB. Which I could accomplish the look and functionality, however those vbruntimes are not installed on some machines :(

Is it possible to use the IE webBrowser control from c++ or even assembly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could statically link the runtime and dynamically link the web-view.

Comment: i don't follow you... 
Can you statically link the vbrun60 files? in vs6?

Comment: I know the IE webbrowser will be there. I don't know that the vb6 runtimes will be there. Thus vb won't work. I wasn't referring to c++vs. I asked if c++ or assembly could use the IE webbrowser, or does anyone have a suggestion how to get around it.

Comment: I was referring to the C++ VS runtime. I somehow assumed you were referring to the C++ VS runtime when actually you were referring to the VBruntime. So we created a big mess in not getting each other :D ... sorry! In short, yes you can use the browser component from C++.

Comment: Statically linking or installation is not needed at all. Windows will happily load DLLs from the same CD that contained the EXE. That includes the C++ runtime DLLs. You should test if it also works with vbrun60, which might require installation.

Answer (score 1):

It appears, [Lucian Wischik's Webform](http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/webform.html) can be a good starting point to meet your minimalistic project requirements. Alternatively, you could host `WebBrowser` ActiveX control directly [using ATL AxHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9d0714y1.aspx). ATL can be linked statically and adds a very low size overhead to the final EXE. Here is [a sample project of WebBrowser host app](http://goo.gl/XFuhUk) which only depends on ATL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the browser component from C++.

C++ however will again need runtime libraries, similar to VB. The good news is, you can statically link those runtime libraries with the executable.

You will not be able to statically link the browser component with your executable, but that wont be an issue unless you try to support ancient Windows versions (pre NT 4.0). For all more recent Windows versions, you can pretty much assume that this component is available.

For more details on that component, you may refer to the [CHtmlView class reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42h6dke4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) - that is the MFC wrapped version of that WebBrowser activeX component.

Using that component from assembler certainly is possible as well, but unless you are deeeeeeep into system programming on the windows platform, you will fail.